# Which *nix user runs commands executed by "system" in Ruby/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

When we run a system command like:

```
system("mv file.txt my_file.txt")
```

Which *nix user runs it really?

Comment: By the way that example is a very bad example. I hope you are not expecting a noob to try that command. You should change it to something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whomever is running the ruby.

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> system("whoami")
sawa
=> true


$ sudo irb
[sudo] password for sawa: ******
irb(main):001:0> system("whoami")
root
=> true
```

Comment: What about in production environment? Does it make any difference? I'm having a hard time to execute a command (including sudo) which needs to be performed by my application... My deployer user is already a root and set up with NoPassword.

Comment: You mean in Rails console?

Comment: No, inside the application.

Comment: I am not entirely sure about the setting you have, and I cannot say anything about it. Why not try `system("whoami")` on it? It will tell you.

Comment: I tried ``whoami`` but can't get any strings back even though my log level is :debug. I think I'd better use `Popen3`.

Comment: I tried Open3 too but I still can not see result of `whoami`. It's really weired. I can see the result in production console but not in production log.

Comment: You might have a `PATH` issue; try `system("/usr/bin/whoami")` or `system("/usr/bin/whoami > /tmp/whoami.out")` then look inside `/tmp/whoami.out`

Answer (score 3):

`system` (probably in [Ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-system) an interface to the C [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) library function) is just the standard mix of `fork` then `execve` of `/bin/sh -c` ; read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) for more.

Neither [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) nor [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) -on a non-[setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) program like `/bin/sh`- changes the user running that program. See [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html)

Hence the user is unchanged. It is the same user who started ruby.

And nothing happens in the *background*. Read about [job control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_%28Unix%29).

Comment: Your edits have blown my mind Basile :D Thank you very much for details. +1 goes to you.